# Xdebug trace format 1 output

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I'm using *xdebug_start_trace* and xdebug_stop_trace with trace_format 1. The output I get isn't starting the function number at 1, and the entry isn't starting at zero as well. Here are the first three lines of the trace log:

```
TRACE START [2012-02-09 00:55:43]  
2  162   1  0.038159 820608  
2  163   0  0.038272 821720   require_once   1  /Users/kint/dev/proj/source/f.inc /Users/kint/dev/proj/www/test.php  72  
2  163   1  0.038286 821720
```

Shouldn't the function # (2nd column) start with 1 (instead of 162), and shouldn't the first `"entry/exit"` value be 0? What am I doing wrong? This is messing up my profiling.

Addendum:
It seems like the function number is an absolute value from where the execution begins. If I put my *xdebug_start_trace* in the middle of the file, and I got the 162 value. However, if I move the xdebug_start_trace further up the function, the function number decreases. Since that seems to be the answer, I wonder if there's a way to reset this count?

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug starts counting functions from when the script starts, so your trace files starting with 162 is perfectly all right. The first exit you see (162:1) is from the xdebug_start_trace() function itself (which could be defined as a bug I suppose).
There is no way how to reset the number at the moment, but you can of course always add a feature request at http://bugs.xdebug.org/my_view_page.php

cheers,
Derick